# how to call data from database to view by user_role laratrust

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laratrust

I use laratrust as my user role, in the user role there are 1 = superadministrator, 2 = administrator, 3 = perusahaan, then I want to display the names of existing perusahaan in my view, which means calling user = role id 3, then how to call it? I also don't really understand eloquent relationships

Answer (score 0):

You need to get users in this way

```
// This will return the users with 'superadministrator' role.
$users = User::whereRoleIs('superadministrator')->get();
```

check the [documentation](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/querying-relationships.html#by-role)